# Audio Messaging Interchange Specification

Tags: telephony, voicemail

Audio Messaging Interchange Specification. I am attempting to locate a copy of this rather old specification. Can anyone recommend where I might find this? All my searches have turned up endless references to glossaries but no actual specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/unity/white/paper/mig/AMIS.html) is a start, but admitably it's not the complete specification.  Perahps it's enough for your purposes though.  There are actually two, AMIS-A (analog) and AMIS-D (digital).

Comment: Close enough for what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @DarkFalcon That's Fantastic! It was definitely illusive.  I'm happy it was what you needed.  Thanks.